# Unsplash API - Access specific photo by id

Tags: python, api, rest, insomnia

I want to access a specific photo via the Unsplash API and a given photo ID. Unfortunately my approaches didn't succeed and it seems that no other person on google tried it yet.

#### Prerequisite

- Register at [unsplash developers](https://unsplash.com/developers) to get your access key.

#### Unsplash API Documentation

As stated [here](https://unsplash.com/documentation#get-a-photo):

```
Endpoint: https://api.unsplash.com/

GET /photos/:id
```

Provide as a parameter the *photo's id* as well as your *access key*:

- Example photo: https://unsplash.com/photos/nDV6ahWLvEg

  - Last part is the photo id (I assume, based on readings I did): `nDV6ahWLvEg`
- Provide your access key as `client_id`, e.g. `123123123123`

#### My full GET string:

```
https://api.unsplash.com/photos/:id?id=nDV6ahWLvEg&client_id=123123123123
```

#### Error Response

I always get an `404 - Couldn't find photo`. Authorization works, tried this with other unsplash endpoints. Tried to access it via python ´request` package and Insomnia (REST Client), both the same error. Tried also the "collections endpoint" who also needs an id (collection id) - error 404.

I assume that I do something wrong with the `:id ? id = ...`

---

Has anybody an idea?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RESTful API can make use of different types of parameters, e.g.

- Query parameters: they appear at the end of the URL after the question mark
- Path parameters: they are added in the path of an endpoint just before the question mark

The Unsplash API makes use of both types of parameters. `client_id` is a query parameter while `id` is a path parameter. You can recognize this by the colon (:) used in the documentation (`/photos/:id`).

Thus you must replace `:id` with the actual photo id. You request looks then like:

```
https://api.unsplash.com/photos/nDV6ahWLvEg?client_id=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
```